# C# how drag borderless window with menuStrip?

Tags: c#

How do I drag borderless Form? I tried almost everything but most of the solutions are pretty confusing as I don't have decent experience in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i find this approach. feel free to delete if its duplicate but for me it looks the most simple.

in order to drag window we need some sort of loop that runs while we have mouse button pressed, im doing it with timer.
also we need variable that will store initial mouse press location.

```
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Timer moveTimer;
        private static Point pnt;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            moveTimer = new Timer();
            moveTimer.Interval = 0.1;
            moveTimer.Enabled = false;
            moveTimer.Elapsed += moveTimerEvent;
            moveTimer.AutoReset = true;
        }
```

next we just add MouseDown and MouseUp Events to every control we want to be able to move window. usually i have this event on menustrip like most browsers do nowadays but you can use any control

```
private void AddHub_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pnt = new Point(e.Location.X+(sender as Control).Location.X, e.Location.Y + (sender as Control).Location.Y);
            moveTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
private void AddHub_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            moveTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
```

we are getting mouse location with respect to control with `e.location` and then controls location with respect to form with `(sender as Control).Location`
so mouse location with respect to form is mouse location with respect to control + controls location with respect to form

and finally we use timer event `moveTimerEvent` to actually drag a window

```
private void moveTimerEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - pnt.X, Cursor.Position.Y - pnt.Y); }));
        }

    }
```

we need to invoke a method as timer `moveTimerEvent` is running in another thread and cant directly affect `Form1`.
this is a pseudo code to calculate `Form1` location from mouse location: `Form1.location = Cursor.Position - pnt` and this location is with respect to screen.